# How to find a rectangle's rotation amount that is inscribed inside an axis-aligned rectangle?

Tags: geometry, rotations, rectangles

We have a rotated rectangle (the shaded shape) whose dimensions are determined through the parameters of $m$ and $n$. The rectangle is then enclosed inside an axis-aligned rectangle whose dimensions are represented through the $W$ and the $H$ parameters (the dashed box).

How may we calculate the rectangle's rotation amount with respect to the specified parameters?
 (named $\alpha$ in the figure below.)

[image: How to find the rotation amount of an inscribed rectangle that is inside an axis-aligned rectangle]

---

*<sup>**P.S.**: The parametric dimensions of the shaded rectangle are considered after [@dxiv](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/291201/dxiv)'s [wise comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615711/how-to-find-a-rectangles-rotation-amount-that-is-inscribed-inside-an-axis-align?noredirect=1#comment5402091_2615711); indicating that without the further information, the issue if facing with insufficiency of information to uniquely determine the $\alpha$.</sup>*

Comment: `We have a rotated rectangle ... whose width and height are not specified` There are many different rectangles inscribed into the axes-aligned one. Each one corresponds to a different $\,\alpha\,$, so you need some additional information to determine a unique $\,\alpha\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Hi and tnx for the reply. Actually, the axis-aligned rectangle is created upon the rotated one (it's not the other way around), thus the $\alpha$ is unique.

Comment: It doesn't matter what's created from what. If the end figure is what you drew, and if you only know $W$ and $H$, then that's not enough information to determine $\alpha$. Consider for example that, on your drawing, the shaded rectangle could be identical to the dotted one, corresponding to $\,\alpha=0\,$. And there are inifnitely many others in between.

Comment: @dxiv So, it's about the shortage of information and not the uniqueness of the $\alpha$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. There is simply insufficient information to uniquely determine $\,\alpha\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for the clarification, I appreciate it :) I've update the question, could you please take a look at it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Too long for a comment*.)  The problem is now **over**determined, after the latest edit. For solutions to exist, it is necessary that the projections onto the axes-aligned rectangle add up:

$$
\begin{align}
n \cos(\alpha)+m\sin(\alpha)=W \\
n \sin(\alpha)+m\cos(\alpha)=H
\end{align}
$$

The first equation is equivalent to $\,\sin(\varphi+\alpha)= \dfrac{W}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}\,$, where $\,\varphi=\operatorname{arctan}\left(\dfrac{n}{m}\right)\,$. If this equation has solutions i.e. $\,\dfrac{W}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}} \le 1\,$, ***and*** if the solutions also satisfy the second equation, then the answer is $\,\alpha = \arcsin\left({\dfrac{W}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}}\right)-\arctan\left(\dfrac{n}{m}\right)\,$ normalized to the $1^{st}$ quadrant.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  Regarding the question `"could the problem be solved when having only m in hand (but not the n) or vice-versa"`, the answer is affirmative but the solution amounts to solving a quartic equation. With the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) in $\,t = \tan(\alpha / 2)\,$, the equations become:

$$
\begin{align}
n (1-t^2)+2mt=W(1+t^2) \\
2n t+m(1-t^2)=H(1+t^2)
\end{align}
$$

Eliminating $\,n\,$ between the equations gives the quartic in $\,t\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
2t \big(\cancel{n (1-t^2)}+2mt\big) - (1-t^2)\big(\cancel{2n t}+m(1-t^2)\big) = 2t(1+t^2)W-(1-t^2)(1+t^2)H
$$

Comment: This is way more valuable than a simple +1, I do really appreciate it :) BTW, in what circumstances the first two equations would not satisfy?

Comment: @goodUser Suppose for example you have $W \ne H$ but $m = n$, then the first two equations are inconsistent with one another (which is the same as saying that you can't inscribe a square in a non-square rectangle). That's why the problem is **over**determined now.

Comment: Thanks again; could the problem be solved when having only $m$ in hand (but not the $n$) or vice-versa? (The $W$ and $H$ are always there :)

Comment: @goodUser It could be solved, but it's not necessarily pretty. See my latest edit.

Comment: This is really great! and I'm sure you are far greater. You are a hero! I truly appreciate you.